# iTerm2 not respecting my key bindings...sometimes

Tags: macos, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2, haskell

I have my iTerm2 keybindings set to have command+left arrow and command+right arrow move the cursor to the beginning and end of the line. This works most of the time. But not when I am in ghci (the Haskell interpreter)

It works in other interpreters though (I've tried python and sh)

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my shell (bash 3.2) or with iTerm2 (Build 1.0.0.20130319) with my ghci (7.4.2) but its very annoying. Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ghci uses haskeline instead of readline. If you remapped ⌘← and ⌘→ to \e[H and \e[F, add this to ~/.haskeline:

```
keyseq: "\ESC[H" ctrl-a
keyseq: "\ESC[F" ctrl-e
```

You could also remap ⌘← and ⌘→ to ⌃A and ⌃E.

See http://trac.haskell.org/haskeline/wiki/CustomKeyBindings.